# Multiply value of field based on value range CASE? COALESCE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, case, coalesce, boolean-expression

I have two tables. (MS SQL Server 2012)

**Performance**

```
 PortfolioID PortfolioCode  Date        MarketValue
    1         Port1         12/31/12    100000
    2         Port2         12/31/12    200000
    3         Port3         12/31/12    300000
```

**BillingRates**

```
RateID  FromRate        ToRate      Rate
1       1               100000      1
2       100000.01       200000      0.99
3       2000000.01      300000      0.98
4       300000.01       400000      0.97
```

I want to run a query that has something like a CASE statement where I say if the MarketValue of a portfolio on a particular date is between the variousvalue ranges within the tiers on the rates table than its marketvalue is multiplied by its respective rate. (The rate column represents percentage rates)

For example

```
Port1 falls in the RateID 1 tier and is multiplied by 1    100,000 * 1% = 1000
Port2 falls in the RateID 2 tier and is multiplied by .99  200,000 * .99% = 1980
Port3 falls in the RateID 3 tier and is multiplied by .98  300,000 * .98% = 2940
```

I have about 100 of these 'cases' and was thinking of doing something like this

```
SELECT COALESCE(
CASE WHEN condition1 THEN calculation1 ELSE NULL END,
CASE WHEN condition2 THEN calculation2 ELSE NULL END,
etc...
)
```

But I can't figure out the logic or how to best join the two tables to achieve this.

Comment: What database system are you using? If you have a lot of these conditions then it would probably be best to create a procedure to do this (if the calculation is similar but different values)

Comment: A procedure could work but I'm not sure of the logic to get the market value to be multiplied by the correct rate based on the rate tier it falls in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to join them like this:

```
select p.*, p.MarketValue * br.rate
from Performance p left outer join
     BillingRates br
     on p.MarketValue between br.[from] and br.[to]
```

This is called a non-equijoin.  The performance on such joins is generally worse than on equi-joins.  Having an index on `[from], [to]` will help.

Also, you shouldn't use SQL reserved words as column names.  That is, "from" and "to" are inconvenient names.

If there might not be a match, then you might want:

```
select p.*, p.MarketValue * coalesce(br.rate, 1.0)
```

so the result is not `NULL`.

Comment: I can change the from and to to be frromrateand torate

Comment: changed the names to fraomrate and torate

Answer (score 1):

This how you would go about creating a procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test @MarketValue int
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @rate decimal;

SET @rate = (SELECT rate 
             FROM billingrates 
             WHERE @marketvalue > "from" AND @marketvalue < to)

--Add your calculation and return/output value here
--@rate * @marketvlaue

END
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt but something seems to be missing here. I need to pull information from the performance table like the portfoliocode, date, and market value to be cross referenced against the rate on the billingrates table. I don't see that happening here.

Comment: You could easily modify this to take in the portfolio id and date (or what ever you want) and then using that id select all the information you need to do your calculation and output what you need. Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure/) on how to create stored procedures. I could update for you but I don't fully understand the output you are after and what you are providing as input.

Comment: This was the query I ended up using. Note that Performance and BillingRates are on two different tables.

Comment: select p.PortfolioBaseCode, p.PerfDate, p.MarketValue, br.rate, p.MarketValue * coalesce((br.rate/100)/4, 1.0) as 'Quarterly_Fee'

from APXFirm.AdvApp.vPerformance p left outer join
     DVAFirm.dbo.BillingRates br
     on p.MarketValue between br.fromrate and br.torate

Comment: Could you help put this into a Stored Procedure?

Comment: What do you want the procedure to do or do you just want to store the query? What do you want the output of the procedure to be? And how do you want to call the procedure?

Comment: Hey Java Devil. The procedure probably isn't necessary in this case.